# How to pass external query string param value to minified angularjs file

Tags: angularjs

My angularjs project which is minified and bundled(build.js) file using gulp need to take some external param value to function.So how can I take this query string param value inside the application for using them to call API services

script src="bundle.js?param1=abc"

Can I use $location.search() inside a service module, but as this param is not passed on browser location will it work with script tag

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a parameter to the server, not the application. There are some workarounds to pass parameter from the template/view to the controller, eg you can do the following:

```
<script>
    window.data = window.data || {};
    window.param1 = 'abc';
</script>
```

This way you can reach `window.param1` inside your js webapp, as it's a global variable.

But the good practice is to controll the template from the webapp, and not the other way.